# How to read multiple tables from one TXT file in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a text file that looks like this,

```
data = '''1|b|c 
2|e|f|g|h|i|j|k
2|2|3|4|5|6|7|8
1|e|f'''
```

I want to use pandas to create multiple tables from the data.

1. Create table with rows starting with 1
2. Create table with rows starting with 2

What is the recommended fast & easy way to get this done using pandas ?

Comment: why `pandas`? why not just read the file, split on `|` and then do stuffs with output list?

Comment: Pandas has a lot of in-built functions for parsing files and creating data frames. If it can be done using those functions i don't have to write something on my own that already exists.

Answer (score 1):

You can just set delimiter on `pandas` read, as in:

```
# Or .read_table
master_table = pd.read_csv("file.txt", delimter="|")

# Select just the rows where an arbitrary column is 1.
df1 = master_table[master_table["column_name"] == 1].copy()
```

Perhaps it is simpler to iterate through the file:

```
with open("file.txt", "r") as file:
      for line in file:
           if line[0] == 1: # Check any arbitrary condition
               # Process the data
```